# How to put a type annotation in an iterator's collect statement?

Tags: rust

I have this code:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};

fn load_file() -> Vec<String> {
    let file = BufReader::new(File::open("foo.txt").unwrap());
    file.lines().map(|x| x.unwrap()).collect();
}

fn main() {
    let data = load_file();
    println!("DATA: {}", data[0]);
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get this error:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations required: cannot resolve `_: std::iter::FromIterator<std::string::String>`
 --> src/main.rs:6:38
  |
6 |     file.lines().map(|x| x.unwrap()).collect();
  |                                      ^^^^^^^
```

In fact, if I change the `load_file` function in this way, the code compiles smoothly:

```
fn load_file() -> Vec<String> {
    let file = BufReader::new(File::open("foo.txt").unwrap());
    let lines: Vec<String> = file.lines().map(|x| x.unwrap()).collect();
    return lines;
}
```

This solution is not "Rusty" enough because ending a function with a return is not encouraged.

Is there a way to put the type annotation directly into the `file.lines().map(|x| x.unwrap()).collect();` statement?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In fact your problem was slightly less noticeable. This does not compile (your initial piece of code):

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};

fn load_file() -> Vec<String> {
    let file = BufReader::new(File::open("foo.txt").unwrap());
    file.lines().map(|x| x.unwrap()).collect();
}

fn main() {
    let data = load_file();
    println!("DATA: {}", data[0]);
}
```

But this does:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};

fn load_file() -> Vec<String> {
    let file = BufReader::new(File::open("foo.txt").unwrap());
    file.lines().map(|x| x.unwrap()).collect()
}

fn main() {
    let data = load_file();
    println!("DATA: {}", data[0]);
}
```

Can you notice the subtle difference? It's just a semicolon in the last line of `load_file()`.

Type inference in Rust is strong enough not to need an annotation here. Your problem was in that you was ignoring the result of `collect()`! The semicolon acted like a "barrier" for the type inference, because with it `collect()`'s return type and `load_file()`'s return type are not connected. The error message is somewhat misleading, however; it seems that this phase of type checking ran earlier than the check for return types (which would rightly fail because `()` is not compatible with `Vec<String>`).

Answer (score 38):

[`Iterator::collect`'s signature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) looks like this:

```
fn collect<B>(self) -> B
where
    B: FromIterator<Self::Item>,
```

In your case, you need to tell it what `B` is. To specify the types of a generic function, you use syntax called the *turbofish*, which looks like `func::<T, U, ...>()`

Your `load_file` function should look like this:

```
fn load_file() -> Vec<String> {
    let file = BufReader::new(File::open("foo.txt").unwrap());
    file.lines().map(|x| x.unwrap()).collect::<Vec<String>>()
}
```

You can also allow some type inference to continue by specifying some types as the placeholder `_`:

```
fn load_file() -> Vec<String> {
    let file = BufReader::new(File::open("foo.txt").unwrap());
    file.lines().map(|x| x.unwrap()).collect::<Vec<_>>()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Also if this is not the "correct" solution to my specific problem. I was really looking for the syntax for specifying type annotation in function calls. This will be useful in the future for sure. ;)