# What is the difference between type casting by setting the type of a variable and using `as`?

Tags: rust

What is the difference between these two cases? Why does the commented line compile but the last line in the main is incorrect?

How to cut string (`substr` in C++ with non-const arguments) without an extra variable?

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io;
use std::io::Read;

fn read_string(filename: &str) -> Result<String, io::Error> {
    let mut s = String::new();
    File::open(filename)?.read_to_string(&mut s)?;
    Ok(s)
}

fn main() {
    let s = read_string("tt.txt").expect("Wow");

    // let s2: String = s.chars().skip(0).take(s.len() -2).collect();

    println!(
        "{}",
        s.chars().skip(0).take(s.len() - 2).collect() as String
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue lies in the `.collect()` method. From it's [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect):

> Because `collect()` is so general, it can cause problems with type
>   inference. As such, `collect()` is one of the few times you'll see the
>   syntax affectionately known as the 'turbofish': `::<>`. This helps the
>   inference algorithm understand specifically which collection you're
>   trying to collect into.

The compiler cannot infer the collection type you want to use, hence the need to specify it explicitly.

Some examples:

```
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("magic");

    //different ways to specify the target type
    //1. -> explicitly declaring the variable type
    //2. -> turbofish syntax (great article about it: https://matematikaadit.github.io/posts/rust-turbofish.html)

    let a1: String = s.chars().skip(0).take(s.len() - 2).collect();
    let a2 = s.chars().skip(0).take(s.len() - 2).collect::<String>();

    let b1: Vec<char> = s.chars().skip(0).take(s.len() - 2).collect();
    let b2 = s.chars().skip(0).take(s.len() - 2).collect::<Vec<char>>();

    let c1: HashSet<char> = s.chars().skip(0).take(s.len() - 2).collect();
    let c2 = s.chars().skip(0).take(s.len() - 2).collect::<HashSet<char>>();
}
```

As the examples show, many target types are valid and there is no way for the compiler to decide what your intention was.

Answer (score 4):

Explicitly typing a variable is **not** a type cast.

As thoroughly explained elsewhere, [`Iterator::collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) requires knowing the concrete type to collect into.

A type cast, such as that performed by `as`, requires converting from one type to another. You've specified the *second* type (`String`), but there's still no way for the compiler to deduce what the *first* type should be.

#### Turbofish

The syntax you want in today's Rust is the *turbofish*:

```
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let s = fs::read_to_string("tt.txt").expect("Wow");

    println!(
        "{}",
        s.chars().skip(0).take(s.len() - 2).collect::<String>()
    );
}
```

- [How to put a type annotation in an iterator's collect statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27909064/155423)
- [What is the syntax: `instance.method::<SomeThing>()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52360464/155423)

#### Type Ascription

As a nightly feature, you could also use the experimental *type ascription*:

```
#![feature(type_ascription)]

use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let s = fs::read_to_string("tt.txt").expect("Wow");

    println!(
        "{}",
        s.chars().skip(0).take(s.len() - 2).collect(): String
    );
}
```

- [What is type ascription?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36389974/155423)

#### Other

You don't need to write `read_string`.

- [What's the de-facto way of reading and writing files in Rust 1.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31192956/155423)